# I need help putting together a POST/PUT/GET request for my ESP32

Tags: httpclient, esp32, arduino-esp32

Can someone post an example code for sending data in a URL using HTTPClient on a ESP32 (I'm using dweet as an example, I have a different site)?

Say I have a sensor data of temperature (24'C - nevermind the "'C", sensor only shows the number which is what I want) and humidity (30%) and want to send those as URL like this: http://dweet.io/sensor.php?temperature=24&humidity=30

I guess header should be "HTTP/1.0".

Ways to send over HTTPS without CA or fingerprint would also be helpful.

Practices to avoid memory leaks and to prevent errors or crashes would be a delightful bonus. :-)

Comment: Try to run all the examples that came with the [HTTPClient library](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/HTTPClient/examples) first to understand how to use the library.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the [protocol examples provided by ESP-IDF](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/protocols) to be very helpful. And there are [some tutorials](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-http-get-post-arduino/) that help with writing those requests as well.

If you do not want to use a CA and just want to have https for testing purposes, then I have found the [https-mbedtls](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/protocols/https_mbedtls) example provided by ESP-IDF to be very helpful here, as there is an option to optionally verify the certificate. MBEDTLS_SSL_VERIFY_OPTIONAL can be set to MBEDTLS_SSL_VERIFY_NONE in the https_mbedtls_example_main.c file meaning that you can use self-signed certificates without receiving an error.